# Why is the console asking for input even though there is no input in code?

Tags: c++

I'm taking an online computer science class for grade 12 and we're using c++. I've never touched c++ and I'm starting to wish I never had. The teacher is comparing c++ to java (a language I can use perfectly fine) and we're currently learning how to input and output strings and chars. The simple practice problem was

> Use one of fputc(), putc(), or putchar() to print your name one char at a time.

Since I have no clue how to use fputc() or putc() I decided to go with putchar()

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    cout << "My name is :" << endl;
    putchar('J');
    putchar('a');
    putchar('c');
    putchar('o');
    putchar('b');

    return 0;
}
```

I tried just using putchar(), and then added the cout, and have tried restarting eclipse, etc. but every time I run the program, the console asks for an input. There should not be an input for this program at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your program from outside of the IDE and see what happens. When you launch a console program from inside of an IDE, a new console window is created to run the program in. When the program ends, the console window will close. Many IDEs setup the console to wait for you to press a key, giving you a chance to see the program's output, before the window closes.

Comment: where else would I run it? New to using eclipse as an IDE and haven't had this problem before

Comment: @Fluenzia manually open your OS's console terminal (ie, cmd.exe on Windows, etc) and run your console program from there.